# How to Implement LockService in Google App Script The Right Way?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

Currently, I'm trying lockservice in Google App Script to handle concurrency on my webapp. However, when I implement it, it did not work.

Description of my webapp:
[image]

Whenever a user click on the button, it will get the website address value in the google sheet and open a new window to go to the website. Then, it will update the value in my google sheet with the value of a new website address.

on this webapp, it will cycle through 3 websites **Google -> Youtube -> Facebook**

The problem:

When I tried testing it for concurrency with clicking the button fast, it will return the same website. For example, if I clicked it twice, it will open 2 new window of **Google**, but the value in the google sheet will be updated to **Facebook**, which skip the **Youtube**.

I tried implement **lockservice** but it did not work, maybe I implement it wrongly.

this is my HTML code:

```
    <html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="content">
    <h1>Please Click Below</h1>
    <!-- <h2><?=web?>:</h2> -->
    <button class="button" id = "btn" type="submit" >Open Window</button>
    </div>        
  <script>
  document.getElementById("btn").addEventListener("click", doStuff);
  var web = "";

  function doStuff() {
        google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(openWebsite).getWebsite();
      }

      function openWebsite(web) {
        if (web === "Google") {
          window.open("https://www.google.com/");
        } else if (web === "Youtube") {
          window.open("https://www.youtube.com/");
        } else {
          window.open("https://www.facebook.com/");
        }
        google.script.run.setWebsite();
      }
</script>

  </body>
</html>
```

My code.gs:

```
    var url = "google sheet url";
var web = "";

function doGet(e) {
 
  let tmp = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("index");
  let output = tmp.evaluate().addMetaTag('viewport', 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1');
  return output;

}

function setWebsite () {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url);
  var ws = ss.getSheetByName("website");
  web = ws.getRange(1,1,1,1).getValue();
  var lock = LockService.getScriptLock(); //del
  lock.tryLock(5000); //del
  if (lock.hasLock()) { //del
    if (web === "Google") {
      ws.getRange(1,1,1,1).setValue("Youtube");
    } 
      else if (web === "Youtube") {
      ws.getRange(1,1,1,1).setValue("Facebook");
    }
      else {
      ws.getRange(1,1,1,1).setValue("Google");
    } 

    var xs = ss.getSheetByName("data");
    xs.appendRow([new Date(), web]);
    lock.releaseLock(); //del
    }
  } //del

function getWebsite() {  
  var lock = LockService.getScriptLock();
  lock.tryLock(5000); // wait 5 seconds try to get lock 

  if (lock.hasLock()) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url);
    var ws = ss.getSheetByName("website");
    var web = ws.getRange(1,1,1,1).getValue();
    lock.releaseLock();
    return web;
    }
  }

// function getWebsite() {  
//   var lock = LockService.getScriptLock();
//   try {
//     lock.waitLock(5000); // wait 5 seconds try to get lock
//   } catch (e) {
//     Logger.log('Could not obtain lock after 5 seconds.');
//   }
//     Utilities.sleep(1000);
//     var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url);
//     var ws = ss.getSheetByName("website");
//     var web = ws.getRange(1,1,1,1).getValue();
//     lock.releaseLock();
//     return web;
//     //lock.releaseLock();
//     }
```

ps. I tried two different ways (on the comment part in code.gs) that I can find on Stackoverflow and youtube but still no success.

Please help. Thank you.

Comment: When it is 'locked', no value is returned from `getWebsite()` that `web` is `undefined`. Therefore, the block with `window.open("https://www.facebook.com/");` would be executed. Please try to change the `else` into `else if (web === "Facebook")`.

Comment: In addition, you may also need to insert `if (!web) { return; }` to the first line of `openWebsite(web)` because you do not want `google.script.run.setWebsite();` to be executed when it is 'locked'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I thought that in your script, when the button is clicked, `google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(openWebsite).getWebsite()` is run and also `google.script.run.setWebsite()` is run in the function `openWebsite`. In this case, the LockService is used for each function of `getWebsite()` and `setWebsite()`. I thought that this might be the reason of your issue. So, in your script, how about the following modification? In this modification, one LockService is used for the functions of `getWebsite()` and `setWebsite()`.

#### HTML&Javascript side:

Please modify `openWebsite(web)` in your Javascript side as follows.

##### From:

```
google.script.run.setWebsite();
```

##### To:

```
// google.script.run.setWebsite();
```

- In this modification, `google.script.run.setWebsite();` is removed.

#### Google Apps Script side:

Please modify `getWebsite()` in your Google Apps Script side as follows.

##### From:

```
var web = ws.getRange(1,1,1,1).getValue();
lock.releaseLock();
```

##### To:

```
var web = ws.getRange(1, 1, 1, 1).getValue();
setWebsite(); // Added
lock.releaseLock();
```

- In this modification, `google.script.run.setWebsite();` is removed.

#### Note:

- **When you modified the Google Apps Script, please modify the deployment as a new version. By this, the modified script is reflected in Web Apps. Please be careful this.**
- You can see the detail of this in the report of "[Redeploying Web Apps without Changing URL of Web Apps for new IDE](https://gist.github.com/tanaikech/ebf92d8f427d02d53989d6c3464a9c43)".

Comment: Thank you for answering @Tanaike. I see how I did it wrong. I just tested it and your solution worked! Thank you again. Have a nice day and keep warm.

Comment: @ddhalim Thank you for replying and testing it. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.